# Not able to remove DropDown buttons from relatedList in Lightning mode

Tags: lightning-experience

I have to remove **New** button from related list in detail page. That I was able to do , but I am still seeing DropDown Button in related List, which show Edit,Delete in disable mode.
 [image: See in Red block]